# FQL Query Returning Empty Attachment Array

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When I run the following query in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), sometimes posts with photo attachments return an empty attachment array, instead of the attachment data. Other posts with photos return attachment data as expected.

```
SELECT post_id,attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id=120696471425768 LIMIT 20
```

I end up with this in the returned data:

```
"attachment": {
    "description": ""
},
```

I have verified that these posts indeed do have photos attached to them. One thing I have noted is that posts with empty attachment data have the type 'status' as opposed to 'photo', when they really should be 'photo'.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Is it a permissions issue, possibly that the posting user hasn't granted permission for applications to view their photos? This even happens with ALL permissions selected.

Is there a way around this problem?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I think I have figured out the reason why this is happening.

It is a permissions issue, and one that any app owner has no control over. 

The person posting the photo post must have 'My Photos' permission checked under App Settings->Apps Others Use.